# Why doesn't my factorial loop end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

I'm working on a series of projects for schoolwork, and this is one of the challenges set:

> Factorial Finder
>
> The Factorial of a positive integer, n, is defined as the product of
>   the sequence n, n-1, n-2, ...1 and the factorial of zero, 0, is
>   defined as being 1.
>
> Solve this using both loops and recursion.

```
num = input("Type number: ")
num1 = str(float(num) - float(1))
fnum = float(num) * float(num1)
while (num1 != 1): 
    num1 = str(float(num) - float(1))
    fnum = float(num) * float(num1)
else:
    print(fnum)"
```

But when it comes to running the code, you input a number and the program outputs nothing, it just sits there. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`num1 != 1` will never be false, because `num1` is a *string*. You also subtract 1 from `num` which itself never changes, so you'd never reach `1` that way *either*; if `num` started at 5 at the start, then `num1` is forever going to be `4`.

Apart from that, you also never multiply with the preceding `fnum` value, instead replacing `fnum` each iteration with the `num * num1` result. If your loop worked correctly, you'd end up with `num * 1` in the end, the wrong answer.

I'm not sure why you are using strings, just keep this as a number. If you insist on using `float` values, take into account that there can be precision issues; better check for numbers equal *or smaller* than one. Subtract 1 from `num1` to count down. There is no need to convert everything to `float()` every time; once you have a floating point number, stick to that:

```
num = float(num)
num1 = num - 1
fnum = num * num1
while num1 > 1: 
    num1 = num1 - 1
    fnum = fnum * num1
```

Your assignment tells you to use *integers* however. The above is now easily converted to using integers instead:

```
num = int(num)
num1 = num - 1
fnum = num * num1
while num1 > 1: 
    num1 = num1 - 1
    fnum = fnum * num1
```

Finally, I'd just use a `for` loop over a `range()`. It doesn't matter if you use `n * n - 1 * n - 2 * ... * 1` or `1 * ... * n - 2 * n - 1 * n`; the outcome is the same:

```
num = int(num)
fnum = 1
for i in range(2, num + 1):
    fnum = fnum * i
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because num is never decremented. If num is 5, then inside the while loop num1 will always be 4. Similarly, fnum will always be 20.

If you want a pattern like 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1, num needs to actually be decreased by one in the while loop.

Also, why are you turning everything into a string? Your while loop won't even begin if num1 is a string.